# Why cant I find the word n1 in my string using string.Contain C#?

Tags: c#

I am using C# and I have a string

```
string test = "255\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n-1\r\n\r\n255\r\n\r\n1\r";
```

This is the code I use to find n1 in my string.

```
if (test.Contains("n1"))
{
   //do something

}
else
{
  //do something else
}
```

But it keeps going to the else statement when my string does contain n1, why is this and is there an alternative way to find n1 in my string?

Comment: When the letter n is prefixed by \  it means newline There is no n1 in your string but newline1

Comment: "\" will escape characters. Try `test.Contains(@"\n1")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string doesn't contain "n1". `\n` is a newline character. You can disable the escaping by putting a @ in front of the string:

```
string test = @"255\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n-1\r\n\r\n255\r\n\r\n1\r";
```

Then, all `\` are literal backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

The else is executed because `test.Contains("n1")` evaluates to false;Since `\n` will converted to `Environment.NewLine` so there is no `n1` is present in the string; You can use like this to disable escaping `string test = @"\n\n\n\r..."` it will then replace every `\` with `\\` so your search will give you the expected result.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) you can find a list of Escape Sequences
[image]

Comment: @TimSchmelter: correct string literal for what? Wnvironment.NewLine?